# hive determine records with overlapping dates

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have tableA as below, need to find the overlapping dates based on transaction ID

Multiple records for same transaction ID, need to find if there are any overlapping dates and return those records

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.transactionId = t.transactionId and
                    t2.enddate > t.startdate and
                    t2.startdate < t.enddate and
                    -- and not the same record
                    t2.startdate <> t.startdate and
                    t2.enddate <> t.enddate
             );
```

How about phrase the query like this?

```
select t.*
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.transactionId = t.transactionId 
where t2.enddate > t.startdate and
      t2.startdate < t.enddate and
      t2.startdate <> t.startdate and
      t2.enddate <> t.enddate
```

(If you have a unique id, then the last two conditions can be replaced by that.)

You might want `select distinct` if that is possibility.

Comment: this is not working in hive, it says subquery expression startdate refers to both parent and subquery expression,  and is not valid join condition

Comment: the second query did not work, i got 0 records in select statement